# Django allauth - Template include in base.html causes RecursionError

Tags: django, templates, include, django-allauth

I am using allauth to handle all my authentication. Using that app each piece of authentication functionality is given its own template. However, I want to include the registration form in all other templates. i.e. the registration form is present in /account/login/, /account/password/change ... etc...

I decided to achieve that by including signup.html in base.html which is extended in all other templates. Like this:

**base.html**

```
...
<h4 class="card-title text-center">Register</h4>
{% include "account/signup.html" %}
...
```

**account/base.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

**account/signup.html**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

{% for message in messages %}
    <span style="color:red;">{{ message }}</span>
{% endfor %}

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div id="input-group">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value='{% trans "Get started" %}'>
    </div>
</form>
```

**account/login.html**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

{% block general_notice_modal %}
{% endblock general_notice_modal %}

{% block login-modal %}
...
```

This code causes the following error, which only occurs when I add the {% include %} tag in **base.html**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below:

```
{% include "account/signup.html" %}
```

should be in "account/base.html" not in "base.html".

You have an error because your "base.html" call "account/signup.html" and your "account/signup.html" call "account/base.html" who call himself "base.html". You have a loop.